# apple distribution cert: "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority" what is the certificate authority?

Tags: ios, app-store

We want to publish an app in the appstore.  The 3rd party who are building it for us need the certificate and profile we create via the apple development portal. According to the docs, the way to create a certificate is to use the mac's keychain application, and select "Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority"

This then prompts for

1. user email address
2. common name
3. CA email address.

The questions are

1. Who/What is the CA in this case?  Do I need to set it up?  Is it a commercial CA, such as thawte? What are they going to do with a random email from this dialog?
2. what should common name be? Can I just enter the name of our company, e.g. "Abc Plc" or does it have to match up with something?
3. Where do I find the CA email address?  Who is the CA?
4. I dont really want my personal email address as the "user email address".  Our org may have "support@abc.com" or similar, but this will go to an unknown department in india, and I wont be able to access it.

I see if you select "save to file" the CA email address becomes non-mandetory. Does this mean that Apple will sign it, or that you need to get the CSR signed via another method?

Answer (score 2):

Answers

1. CA will be Apple only. They only issue the certificate for your development work. You can see all the details once it gets generated.
2. Common name can be anything. On that name certificate's private key file will be created. You can use your company name as well.
3. You can provide your own official email address.

4.You don't get any email from apple. So you can use your own official email address at both places.

No need of CSR signed by any other method.